# Copying data from one table to another automatically using PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql

I have a database with two schemas, "public" and "versioned".
In "versioned" I created a copy of the data contained in "public" that I update daily.

Is there an automatism for the data that I add every day on the tables in "versioned" to add them to the tables in "public" automatically on a daily basis?

Comment: There does not seem to be a GIS component to your pure PostgreSQL question which I think would have been better researched/asked at the [dba.se] Stack Exchange.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Best would be to use a TRIGGER to save any INSERT, UPDATE or DELETE to an audit table. Then you can "rollback" to any state in the original tables for any time.

From this [page](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Audit_trigger):

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION audit.if_modified_func() RETURNS TRIGGER AS $body$
DECLARE
    v_old_data TEXT;
    v_new_data TEXT;
BEGIN
    /*  If this actually for real auditing (where you need to log EVERY action),
        then you would need to use something like dblink or plperl that could log outside the transaction,
        regardless of whether the transaction committed or rolled back.
    */

    /* This dance with casting the NEW and OLD values to a ROW is not necessary in pg 9.0+ */

    IF (TG_OP = 'UPDATE') THEN
        v_old_data := ROW(OLD.*);
        v_new_data := ROW(NEW.*);
        INSERT INTO audit.logged_actions (schema_name,table_name,user_name,action,original_data,new_data,query) 
        VALUES (TG_TABLE_SCHEMA::TEXT,TG_TABLE_NAME::TEXT,session_user::TEXT,substring(TG_OP,1,1),v_old_data,v_new_data, current_query());
        RETURN NEW;
    ELSIF (TG_OP = 'DELETE') THEN
        v_old_data := ROW(OLD.*);
        INSERT INTO audit.logged_actions (schema_name,table_name,user_name,action,original_data,query)
        VALUES (TG_TABLE_SCHEMA::TEXT,TG_TABLE_NAME::TEXT,session_user::TEXT,substring(TG_OP,1,1),v_old_data, current_query());
        RETURN OLD;
    ELSIF (TG_OP = 'INSERT') THEN
        v_new_data := ROW(NEW.*);
        INSERT INTO audit.logged_actions (schema_name,table_name,user_name,action,new_data,query)
        VALUES (TG_TABLE_SCHEMA::TEXT,TG_TABLE_NAME::TEXT,session_user::TEXT,substring(TG_OP,1,1),v_new_data, current_query());
        RETURN NEW;
    ELSE
        RAISE WARNING '[AUDIT.IF_MODIFIED_FUNC] - Other action occurred: %, at %',TG_OP,now();
        RETURN NULL;
    END IF;

EXCEPTION
    WHEN data_exception THEN
        RAISE WARNING '[AUDIT.IF_MODIFIED_FUNC] - UDF ERROR [DATA EXCEPTION] - SQLSTATE: %, SQLERRM: %',SQLSTATE,SQLERRM;
        RETURN NULL;
    WHEN unique_violation THEN
        RAISE WARNING '[AUDIT.IF_MODIFIED_FUNC] - UDF ERROR [UNIQUE] - SQLSTATE: %, SQLERRM: %',SQLSTATE,SQLERRM;
        RETURN NULL;
    WHEN OTHERS THEN
        RAISE WARNING '[AUDIT.IF_MODIFIED_FUNC] - UDF ERROR [OTHER] - SQLSTATE: %, SQLERRM: %',SQLSTATE,SQLERRM;
        RETURN NULL;
END;
$body$
LANGUAGE plpgsql
SECURITY DEFINER
SET search_path = pg_catalog, audit;
```

PS Don't store data in the PUBLIC schema as it makes upgrades much harder.